# Can objects of derived classes in C++ be accessible by parent class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, public

The rules state that an in the case of a public specifier - object of derived class can be treated as object of base class (not vice-versa). What does that mean?

Can all public elements (in any class) be accessible by anything/anywhere?

Does this refer to the fact that for the parent class attributes and methods defined as public are accessible by the derived class. But in the case that the attributes and methods from the derived class are public they aren't accessible by the parent/base class?

```
In a public base class 
Base class members                   How inherited base class members appear in derived class
private:   x ------------------------> x is inaccessible
protected: y ------------------------> protected: y
public:    z ------------------------> public: z
```

but what about in reverse?

Comment: How would you access subclass (non-inherited, non-virtual) members from parent class method's code?

Comment: if i have a `class Circle`. I make an instance of that `circle r;` Accessing the public attribute radius is `r.radius` for example. If i am writing that in my main section then the attribute has to be public. If i wanted to access that same `radius`  within a derived class why wouldn't i be able to do that. Since that method/member is public?

Comment: Simple answer, yes they *can*. The better question is "should they be?". The fact that this is being considered smells a lot like a design that needs to be re-thought, except in some very rare and specialized circumstances, and maybe not even then...

Comment: They probably shouldn't. but i'm trying to get an understanding of all the rules that apply - what can be done - so all scenarios are covered. That's why i wasn't sure with the vise-versa statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the correct question would be "Can **members** (*not objects*) of derived classes in C++ be accessible by parent class?"

Public and protected members (data members and functions) of the base class are accessible to the derived class.

Public members of a class are accessible from anywhere. Of course, they need to be accessed through an instance of that class.

> But in the case that the attributes and methods from the derived class are public theyaren't accessible by the parent/base class?

They can be if you have an instance of the derived class. You can then access the public members of the derived class from the base class.

---

Edit:

Example where base class member accesses public member of derived class and vice versa.

```
class Base
{
    public:
    void funcBase();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    void funcDerived();

};

void
Base::funcBase()
{
    Derived d;
    d.funcDerived();
}

void
Derived::funcDerived()
{
    Base b;
    b.funcBase();
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;

    b.funcBase();
    d.funcDerived();
}
```

Comment: you state - **Public members of a class are accessible from anywhere.** i that case how come methods int he derived class can't access members of the parent class. That's where my confusion is.

Comment: They surely can. That's what I said. Here is an example where derived class member accesses public member of base class and base class member accesses public member of derived class.
class Base
{
    public:
    void funcBase();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    void funcDerived();
    
};

void
Base::funcBase()
{
    Derived d;
    d.funcDerived();
}

void
Derived::funcDerived()
{
    Base b;
    b.funcBase();
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    
    b.funcBase();
    d.funcDerived();
}

Comment: I see. So the base class can access methods in the derived class. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It means if you have `Bar` that is a derived class of `Foo`.

```
class Foo

class Bar : public Foo
```

So you can say, as expected

```
Foo* myFoo = new Foo;
Bar* myBar = new Bar;
```

You can also make a `Foo` from a `Bar` since a `Bar` is a type of `Foo`

```
Foo* myOtherFoo = new Bar;
```

You cannot make a `Bar` from a `Foo`, that is what "object of derived class can be treated as object of base class (not vice-versa)" means.

```
Bar* myOtherBar = new Foo;
```

Comment: So if i understand correctly you can't access Bar from Foo. Because in essence Foo is not a type of Bar. But my confusion is in the case of public variables. If something is public it can be accessed from main or any other random function. Why can't a random function access Bar coming from Foo.

Comment: Because it doesn't know that it's actually a `Bar`. When I said `Foo* myOtherFoo = new Bar;` then everyone publicly using `myOtherFoo` only knows that it is a `Foo`. It also happens to be a `Bar`, but no one knows that. You can only treat it as a `Bar` for `Bar* myBar = new Bar;` because this is actually a pointer to a `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Can objects of derived classes in C++ be accessible by parent class?

Yes. See below for a pattern that I have seen a few times.

You also asked:

> Can all public elements (in any class) be accessible by anything/anywhere?

Yes, of course.

**Example pattern of base class accessing derived class members**

Entity.h:

```
class Attribute;

class Entity
{
   public:
      Entity(Attribute* att);
      void save(FILE* fp);
      void print();

   private:
      Attribute* att_;
};
```

Attribute.h:

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Attribute : public Entity
{
   public:
      void save(FILE* fp);
      void print();

};
```

Entity.cc:

```
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Attribute.h" // Needed to access Attribute member functions

Entity::Entity(Attribute* att) : att_(att) {}

void Entity::save(FILE* fp)
{
   // Save its own data.
   //...

   // Save the Attribute
   att_->save(fp);
}

void Entity::print()
{
   // Print its own data to stdout.
   //...

   // Print the Attribute
   att_->print();
}
```